# Change of variable Theorem's proof for linear transformations

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, riemann-integration

Let $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a rectifiable, bounded, open subset and $T:\ \mathbb R^n\longrightarrow\mathbb R^n$ be a linear map. Let $f:\ T(U)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$.  Suppose $T(U)$ is rectifiable, $f$ is integrable over $T(U)$ and $f\circ T\hspace{.03cm}\big|\det(J_T)\big|$ is integrable over $U$ (in fact, it's known that $f$ is integrable iff $f\circ T\hspace{.03cm}\big|\det(J_T)\big|$ is integrable).

I want to show that $$\intop_{T(U)}f=\intop_{U}f\circ T\hspace{.03cm}\big|\det(J_T)\big|  $$
This theorem has been proved in many materials, but in general case where the map $T$ needs not to be linear. But the technique in these proofs are so difficult and complicated. So how can one prove this theorem for the linear maps ? Is there a more simple way to approach compare to the proofs of general case ? I just have no clue where to start, could someone give me hints to solve this ? Thank you

Comment: What kind of integral are you using? More precisely, when you write $\int_{\Omega} h$ does this mean the Lebesgue integral of $h.1_{\Omega}$ or not?

Comment: I'm cosidering Riemannian/Darboux integral. The notion $\displaystyle\int\limits_{\Omega}h$ here is understand as $\displaystyle\int\limits_{I}h.1_\Omega$ where I is a $n-$rectangle contains $\Omega$

Comment: Are you happy with $\det T$ being the "volume scale factor" upon applying $T$, a property generally established in linear algebra?

Comment: yeah, I think so

Answer (score 0):

Here is at least an outline of how one can show this:

For $1\leq i \leq n$ let $x_i(\mathbf v) = \mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf v$, so that $\mathbf v = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i(\mathbf v).\mathbf e_i$, for all $\mathbf v \in \mathbb R^n$. Then if $T\colon \mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R^n$,
If $T\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is any linear map, then $T$ may be written as a composition of ``elementary linear maps'' of the following form:

$$
\begin{split}
i)& \quad S_{i,j}(\mathbf v) = \sum_{k\notin \{i,j\}} x_k(\mathbf v)e_k + x_j(\mathbf v)\mathbf e_i + x_i(\mathbf v)\mathbf e_j \quad (i,j \in \{1,\ldots, n\}, i\neq j)\\
ii)& \quad E_{ij}(c)(\mathbf v) = \mathbf v + c.x_j(\mathbf v)e_i \quad (i,j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}, i\neq j, c \in \mathbb R)\\
iii)& \quad D_i(c)(\mathbf v) = \sum_{j\neq i} x_j(\mathbf v)\mathbf e_j + cx_i(\mathbf v)\mathbf e_i. \quad (i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}, c \in \mathbb R).
\end{split}
$$
(The fact that any invertible linear map is a composition of such maps is essentially a rephrasing of the basic results about row and column reductions.)

Now we say that a subset $B\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is a "box" if it is of the form $B=[a_1,b_1]\times [a_2,b_2]\times \ldots \times [a_n,b_n]$ where each $[a_i,b_i]$ is a closed non-empty interval in $\mathbb R$. The volume of the box $B$ is defined to be $\nu(B) = \prod_{i=1}^n|b_i-a_i|$. One can then show that if $\mathcal S$ is the $\mathbb R$-linear span of the indicator functions $1_B$ of all boxes $B\subseteq \mathbb R^n$, then there is a unique linear map $\int\colon \mathcal S \to \mathbb R$ such that $\int 1_B = \nu(B)$ for any box $B$. Finally, one extends $\int$ to the class of "Riemann integrable functions" by using, for example, Darboux's upper and lower sums definition.

Now it is immediate from the definition of $\nu(B)$ that if $f\in \mathcal S$, then $\int f\circ T = \int f|\det(T)|$ if $T$ is an elementary linear map of the form $S_{ij}$ or $D_i(c)$, and it not too difficult to argue directly that $\int f\circ T = \int f$ if $T=E_{ij}(c)$ -- note in this case $f\circ T$ need not be in $\mathcal S$.

From this one can show that if $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $\int f\circ T = \int f|\det(T)|$, again in the case where $T$ is an elementary linear map, where in particular this shows that $f\circ T$ is Riemann integrable. But then using induction one sees that $\int f\circ T = \int f|\det(T)|$ for any composition of elementary linear maps, and thus for all linear maps $T$.

Comment: so, could the proof be done even more simply when we restricted the case to only translation maps $T(x) = x + b$  ?

Comment: If you only want to prove that the integral is translation invariant, then yes, that is essentially built in to the definition, in that the upper and lower Darboux sums will be invariant under translation.